# Como usar Easytabs en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, formularios

tengo que hacer un proyecto en vb.net (2017) en donde los formularios se abran como si estos fueran pestañas de chrome.

Investigando un poco vi que la mejor opción y sobre todo gratuita es Easytabs, sin embago todo lo que vi está en C# y no pude llevarlo adelante en VB.net, debido a que el codigo no me deja de tirar error.

Alguien alguna vez lo usó y puede darme una mano?

Namespace Sandbox
Partial Public Class Form1
Inherits Form

```
    Protected ReadOnly Property ParentTabs() As TitleBarTabs
        Get
'el siguiente as me dice que esperaba ')'
            Return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
'aca me dice que no esta delcarado initializeComponent
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub New_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: El codigo deberia ser el mismo, si es vb o c#, solo hay que traducirlo. Tuviste algun problema traduciendolo?

Comment: claro el codigo es el mismo, solamente lo traduje. 
Consta de dos partes, primero crear un form o varios, y luego crear un form madre. A este ultimo no lo cree debido que me daba error el código que inserto en el primer form que cree... dejo un print del error de linea

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Ese codigo no muestra ningun error, o vos no estas mostrando ningun error.. ese componente es para winforms o para wpf?

Comment: Cuando abris la documentacion, dice claramente:  "Instead of inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Form, you inherit from EasyTabs.TitleBarTabs and set the tab renderer that you wish to use:"... no veo que hayas hecho eso en tu codigo...

Comment: es para winforms, le puse arriba como dice la documentacion imports EasyTabs

Comment: de donde estas leyendo la documentacion? porque por lo menos lo que vi en git tiene un ejemplo claro de uso en la portada...